# HC-05 Bluetooth module always sends -1

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I use 2 HC-05 Bluetooth module to communicate between 2 Arduino Nanos.
I already set the baud rate for both HC-05 to 9600, one as master and the other as slave.
The master always sends the value -1, although the value should be from analog input.
I already checked the analog read, and the value is correct.
But when I check the Bluetooth serial reading, the value is -1.
Anyone can help me?

## Master Code

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3);

int state = 0;
const int ledPinon = 8;  //the pin your led is connected to
const int ledPin = 7;  //the pin your led is connected to

int xPin = A1;
int xPosition = 0;
int val = 0;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(xPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  xPosition = analogRead(xPin);
  val = map(xPosition, 0, 1023, 0, 180);

  if (mySerial.available()){
  if (xPosition > 506) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    mySerial.write(val);  //sends a 1 through the bluetooth serial link
  }

  else if ((xPosition <506)||(xPosition >502)){
    mySerial.write('0');
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }

  else if (xPosition <502){
    mySerial.write(val);
    backblink();
  }
  int check = mySerial.read();
  Serial.print(val);
  Serial.print("   |    ");
  Serial.println(check);
  delay(200);
}
}
void ledblink(){
  digitalWrite(ledPinon, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(ledPinon, LOW);
  delay(200);
}

void backblink(){
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(80);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  delay(80);
}
```

## Slave Code

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Servo.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3);

int BluetoothData; // the data given from Computer
Servo ESC;

int state;
const int ledPinon = 8;  //the pin your led is connected to
const int ledPin = 7;  //the pin your led is connected to
const int ledPinback = 6;  //the pin your led is connected to

void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin 8 as an output.

  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  ESC.attach(9);

  ledblink();
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(state);
  if (mySerial.available()>0) { // Checks whether data is comming from the serial port 
    state = mySerial.read(); // Reads the data from the serial port
    BluetoothData = state;
    ESC.write(BluetoothData);
    Serial.println(state);
  }

  // Controlling the LED
  if (BluetoothData > 90) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); // LED ON
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); // LED ON
    //backblink(); // LED ON
  }

}

void ledblink(){
  digitalWrite(ledPinon, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(ledPinon, LOW);
  delay(200);
}

void backblink(){
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  delay(100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the master code all the lines that would possibly send anything to the slave are INSIDE an if that checks for Serial.available.  But since the slave never sends anything to the master, that will always return 0.  So the master probably isn't sending anything at all.

Comment: If there is no data it returns -1 not 0.

Comment: Available won't ever return a negative.  It returns 0 if no data available.  It's read that returns -1 for no data.

Comment: Oh, you are talking about `Serial.available()` not `Serial.read()`. My bad.